# Javascript need to fix code

Tags: javascript

this is my code

```
function howManySundays(num,startDay){
  let Days = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
  for(let i = 0 ; i < num ;i++){
    var value = [];
    value.push(Days[i%7])
    console.log(value)
  }
}
howManySundays(9,"Sunday");
```

and this is the result of code

```
[ 'Monday' ]
[ 'Tuesday' ]
[ 'Wednesday' ]
[ 'Thursday' ]
[ 'Friday' ]
[ 'Saturday' ]
[ 'Sunday' ]
[ 'Monday' ]
[ 'Tuesday' ]
```

How can I find the duplicates in array?

Comment: Remove the `if` and log `i, Days[i % 7]`. See how [Remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) works.

Comment: And one more question how can i cheek if days are repeat?

Comment: ?? If `num` is greater than 7, obviously there are repeated days ...

Comment: By the way, index of array start at 0. Last index of your array is 6. If you want to check something, check `i>6` ;-)

Comment: no no I want to know for example how many times "monday" repeted

Comment: @undefined `Math.ceil((num - Days.indexOf(startDay))/7)` Something like that

Answer (score 0):

Will this help you?

```
function howManySundays(num,startDay){
  let Days = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
  let i = 0;
  while (num > 0) {
    console.log(i, Days[i])
    i++;
    if(i == 7) i = 0;
    num--;
  }
}
howManySundays(9,"Sunday")
```